# Facebook Like button count

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like

Suppose you post a link to a company's facebook fan page.  you need to know whether the person who followed the link to the company's facebook fan page has clicked on the Like button or not.  is there any way to know this?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for analytics that track new fans driven from a shared link. Is that correct?

Comment: Let me explain again.  My website contains a link to a facebook page, and users who have pressed the LIKE button on that facebook page are allowed to gain some points on my website.  I'd like to know if there is an easy way to check if the user trying to earn points on my website has actually pressed the LIKE button on the facebook page, whose link exists on my website.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. One way is to query the `page_fan` table. You'll need to authenticate your user with a minimum of a `read_stream` privilege, then execute this query using the API of your choice.

```
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id="MY_PAGE_ID" AND uid = me()
```

This query will return your user's user id if successful and an empty object if not.

You may be able to write a page app to query the `page_fan` table. I'm not sure if there is an API call that will expose enough information about a user that is logged into Facebook but not your app to identify them without calling the auth process.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'd like to ask you if you understood me correctly.   Let me explain again.  My website contains a link to a facebook page, and users who have pressed the LIKE button on that facebook page are allowed to gain some points on my website.  I'd like to know if there is an easy way to check if the user trying to earn points on my website has actually pressed the LIKE button on the facebook page, whose link exists on my website.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use this code to find out if the user has actually liked your page. "Easy" is a relative term though. Nothing about Facebook and their current auth model is what an outsider would call easy.